# Facebook Webhooks Mentions Event json does not include sender fb user id and user name

Tags: facebook, facebook-webhooks

This is the sample response json which that Facebook sends to the server once some user mentions page in his post (This json is mentioned as the sample json by facebook):

```
    {
      "field": "mention",
      "value": {
        "post_id": "44444444_444444444",
        "sender_name": "Example Name",
        "item": "post",
        "sender_id": "44444444",
        "verb": "add"
      }

}
```

However  the json which I am receiving does not contain sender name and sender id :

```
{
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": {page_id},
            "time":{timestamp},
            "changes": [
                {
                    "field": "mention",
                    "value": {
                        "item": "post",
                        "verb": "add",
                        "message": "{message}",
                        "post_id": "44444444_444444444",
                        "created_time": {timestamp}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "object": "page"

}
```

Can anyone tell me , why Facebook is not sending sender name and sender id .

1. I am using FB API version :3.2
2. Permissions are manage_pages, publish_pages

Comment: probably for privacy reasons

Comment: Is your app in live mode and has everything necessary properly reviewed already, or are you still in dev mode?

Comment: @04FS The Application is in live mode, and its reviewed for manage_pages , and publish_pages

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/page/#mention: _“Some comment_id and post_id fields returned in mention webhooks may not be queried due to missing permissions including privacy issues.”_ - I guess with the `from` field, it is a similar issue. Have you tried this with a user that has logged in to your app beforehand, so that your app has permission to read their basic user info? I suspect the result might be different in that case.